# CrmFetchKit failing this morning - getServerUrl() is undefined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We're using CrmFetchKit for MSCRM 2011 customization in Javascript.  This was never an issue until this morning, now the error I catch in the IE9 script debugger is in CrmFetchKit.js:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined 
CrmFetchKit.js, line 132 character 13

```
function getServerUrl() {

    var serverurl = '',
        // This gets the correct value
        localServerUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host,
        // This gets a value
        context = getContext();

    if (context.isOutlookClient() && !context.isOutlookOnline()) {
        serverurl = localServerUrl;
    }
    else {
        serverurl = context.getServerUrl();
        // This is the line that fails, since the value of serverUrl is undefined
        serverurl = serverurl.replace(/^(http|https):\/\/([_a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)(:([0-9]{1,5}))?/, localServerUrl);
        serverurl = serverurl.replace(/\/$/, "");
    }

    return serverurl;
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated.  We do not know what changed this morning that broke this functionality.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

well, `context.getServerUrl()` is failing. That's as far as anyone can get you without seeing the code for `getServerUrl`. If you'll post the code I'll be happy to edit and give a more detailed answer.

Comment: It looks like it's just this: getServerUrl:function(){return window.SERVER_URL}  However, it appears that within CRM, window.SERVER_URL doesn't work.  It would have to be parent.window.SERVER_URL.  I just don't get how this could've changed overnight.  The original developer just left for vacation

Comment: Just for the heck of it, I tried setting window = parent.window.  Now I'm getting a whole bunch of failures looking for "Type" in all sorts of headers and jscript files

Answer (score 0):

which version of the CrmFetchKit are use using? All my Unit-Tests are green... at least with the latest version.

Try to raise this issue on codeplex, this way I will be notified via mail.

Regards,

Daniel